# Why mutate input data is wrong approach?

Tags: angular

I have a input data in component:

```
@Input() sogllist: any[] = [];
```

Why is the mutation approach like the one here not recommended?

```
public remove(e: any, sogl: any): void {
    this.sogllist = this.sogllist.filter((sgl) => sgl.id !== sogl.id);
}
```

How to do that correctly?

Comment: reading stuff: https://medium.com/@jamesjefferyuk/javascript-what-are-pure-functions-4d4d5392d49c

Comment: I did not get, it illustrates a different example

Comment: The mutation is a bad programming practice. If your code is mutable, you might change or break something without knowing. The code becomes harder to read and test, produces non-predictable side effects. Therefore you better need so-called pure functions. https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-javascript-mutation-and-pure-functions-7231cc2180d3

Comment: Pros. / Cons. of Immutability vs. Mutability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863515/pros-cons-of-immutability-vs-mutability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input should remain unchanged so as to not confuse the flow of things. If you need it to be filtered, try doing something like this:

```
@Input() sogllist: any[] = [];
filteredList: any[];

public remove(e: any, sogl: any): void {
    this.filteredList= this.sogllist.filter((sgl) => sgl.id !== sogl.id);
}
```

You should also give `filteredList` the original value of `sogllist` (either in a setter or in `ngOnInit`) and then replace your usages of `sogllist` with `filteredList`