# Java Stream Methods vs foreach

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a teammate that did all his stream operations in a foreach execution. I tried to come up with advantages of using the filter, map and to list methods instead.

What are other advantages it has other than readability (arguably the foreach is pretty readable as well)
Here is a snippet for something close to what he did:

```java
List<Integer> firstInts = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> secondInts = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> numbersList = IntStream.range(0, max).boxed().toList();


//his stream
numbersList.stream()
       .forEach(i -> {
           if(i % 6 != 0) {
               return;
           }
           secondInts.add(i);
       });


//alternative 1
numbersList.stream()
        .filter(i -> i % 6 == 0)
        .forEach(firstInts::add);


//alternative 2
List<Integer> third = numbersList.stream()
        .filter(i -> i % 6 == 0)
        .toList();
```

what is the motivation of using stream methods other than readability?

Comment: Having side effects in stream methods, e.g. mutating the secondsInt state is frowned upon / not a good idea. It works here because you have a terminal operation and no parallelism but it is still not a good idea.

Comment: the whole idea behind for each is doing side effect operations (it's not part of pure functional programming theory). side effect in general should be avoided, but I can't find a strong argument why use one and not the other in this example

Comment: The major advantage is the possible parallelism. Everything else is just opinion.

Comment: map/filter are composable and lazy. forEach is eager and cannot be composed. Heavily opinion-based.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76004826/java-stream-filter-performance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternative 2 looks best to me in this case

#### 1. Readability

- Alternative 2 has less number of lines
- Alternative 2 read more close to `return a list containing number divisible by 6 from numList`, while forEach approach means add number divisible by 6 from numList to `secondInts`
- `filter(i -> i % 6 == 0)` is straight forward and

  ```
  if(i % 6 != 0) {
      return;
  }
  ```

  require some time for human brain to process.

#### 2. Performance

From [`Stream.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList())

> Implementation Note:
> Most instances of Stream will override this method and provide an implementation that is highly optimized compared to the implementation in this interface.

We benefit from optimization from JDK by using Stream API.

And in this case, using forEach and adding element one by one will be slower, especially when the list is large. It is because `ArrayList` will need to extend it capacity whenever the list full, while Stream implementation `ImmutableCollections.listFromTrustedArrayNullsAllowed` just store the result array into `ListN`.

One more point to note about parallelism:
From [`Stream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer))

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic. For parallel stream pipelines, this operation does not guarantee to respect the encounter order of the stream, as doing so would sacrifice the benefit of parallelism. For any given element, the action may be performed at whatever time and in whatever thread the library chooses. If the action accesses shared state, it is responsible for providing the required synchronization.

```
numbersList.stream().parallel()
       .forEach(i -> {
           if(i % 6 != 0) {
               return;
           }
           secondInts.add(i);
       });
```

Will provide unexpected result, while

```
List<Integer> third = numbersList.stream().parallel()
      .filter(i -> i % 6 == 0).sorted().forEach()
      .toList();
```

is totally fine.

#### 3. Flexibility

Imagine you want the filtered list to be sorted, in forEach approach, you can do it like:

```
numbersList.stream().sorted().
       .forEach(i -> {
           if(i % 6 != 0) {
               return;
           }
           secondInts.add(i);
       });
```

Which is much slower compared to

```
numbersList.stream()
        .filter(i -> i % 6 == 0)
        .sorted()
        .toList();
```

As we need to sort the whole numbersList instead of filtered.

Or if you want to limit your result to 10 elements, it is not straight forward to do so with forEach, but just as simple as adding `limit(10)` when using stream.

#### 4. Less error prone

Stream API usually return Immutable object by default.

From [`Stream.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList())

> Implementation Requirements:
> The implementation in this interface returns a List produced as if by the following:
> Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray())))

Meaning that the returned list is immutable by default. Some advantages of immutability are:

1. You can safely pass the list around to different method without worrying the list is modified.
2. Immutable list are thread safe.

Read [Pros. / Cons. of Immutability vs. Mutability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863515/pros-cons-of-immutability-vs-mutability) for further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it’s an issue of advantages. Each mechanism has a specific purpose.

.forEach() returns void so it doesn’t have an output. The intent is that the elements that the forEach iterates through are not modified. The data in the elements are used for some sort of calculation. I find that forEach is used much less than map. It’s a terminal point in a pipeline.

.filter() takes a stream as input and emits a filtered stream as output. It is for filtering.

.map() is like forEach but it emits a stream of modified objects. It allows the same modification to be done on each each element so that it can be saved, filtered or manipulated further.

.toList is a handy shortcut to turn a stream into a list. Using forEach(List::add) where a toList() will do the work is a terrible idea. You’re preventing Java from bulking the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Streams provide for more readable, functional solution.  But that does come at a cost since the stream API is complex and does a lot under the hood.

If one is going to do everything in a `forEach` block I would just skip the stream solution and go for an imperative solution using a `for loop`.

Otherwise, I would go with `alternative 2` for the reasons cited (lends itself to parallelism, easier to read, etc).  I seldom use `forEach` for anything other than printing although there are always exceptions.

And whether its safe to modify external state in some cases (as in `alternative 1`) I just presume it won't be safe and, with that in mind, focus on the a solution (functional or imperative) that provides the desired result.